# Generate PDF from CI view with html & Highchart Graph on it

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, graph

Hi my requirement is to export pdf file of a codeiginiter view which has html and highchart graph on it through cron i.e should be done on server side i tried phantomjs but it is getting more complex any help or suggestion will be is welcome Thanks

Comment: `what` you have tried ? `what` you have got ? post some code.

Comment: Hi Karan since the main issue is highchart makes graph on client side using highchart.js hence for making graph on server side i tried phantonjs but its getting to much complex

Comment: how about converting graph to image before embedding on the html, then convert the html to pdf.

Comment: I found this phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jakarta&printable=yes' jakarta.pdf which does the work from command line but not executing through php exec() command any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Finally task completed using phantomjs & rasterizejs to generate Highcharts graph on server side and save it as image and then embeded image on pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [domPDF](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php) and [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)? If you can convert the generated graph to image first, it will be much easy to save it to a PDF file.